# Software and USB partition format for creating a bootable USB with Ubuntu on it, on a Mac?

Tags: boot, partitioning, system-installation, usb, mac

This is my first Linux system, and I'm on a Mac running OS X 10.10.5. I used [these steps for downloading Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-mac-osx), but at Step 5 my USB was just not listed at all.

I also just tried using the [Penguintosh](https://penguintosh.com/2012/02/26/linux-usb-creator-released/) software that was posted on several other questions, but I got a message saying that the application was "damaged and I should move it to the trash."

The Ubuntu I downloaded was Version 16.04, 64-bit, and the USB I'm using is a  cheap 4GB Shintaro.

Comment: well maybe you should move it to trash? try to reinstall `penguintosh`.

Comment: No good, I got that same message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I successfully made a bootable USB for Ubuntu 16.04 desktop, from my 2011 iMac, using [UNetbootin](https://unetbootin.github.io/).
The Mac installer link is on that main page. Note that if you want to use it to install onto a Mac, there are further hoops to jump through. This [howtogeek article](http://www.howtogeek.com/213396/how-to-boot-a-linux-live-usb-drive-on-your-mac/) should help.

Comment: The UNetbootin I downloaded was that Mac one, but which hoops? Reformatting the drive in Disk Utility?

I'm downloading the the Mac Linux USB Loader mentioned in the article, see if it works.

Comment: I see, I think I didn't quite read the question correctly, does the USB show up in Disk Utility, but not in UNetbootin?

Comment: No, it showed up in Disk Utility, but it only showed up in UNetbootin when formatted as MS-DOS. But I got it to work using the method on the howtogeek article! Thank you. I had a bit of a derp moment when starting it up though, and accidentally closed the Linux bootup screen. Anyway, thanks!

Comment: Glad it got you there. If my answer helped, could you accept it please? It's the little grey check/tick box on the left hand side of this answer, thanks!

Comment: @Argo USB-sticks are usually MSDOS formatted.